# Count vs. CountDistinct in OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

The examples in [the docs](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.35.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html) about `ConstraintCollectors`' `count()` and `countDistinct()` aren't really clear:

> The `ConstraintCollectors.count(…​)` counts all elements in a group.
> The `ConstraintCollectors.countDistinct(…​)` counts any element in a group once, regardless of how many times it occurs.

I don't see the difference between the two. When combined with `groupBy()`, doesn't both of them return a `BiConstraintStream<A, Integer>` representing tuples of groups of `A` and its corresponding count ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those method are missing javadocs and some examples: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2241

count:

```java
from([
  Person("Ann", "Cole", 20),
  Person("Beth", "Cole", 20),
  Person("Carl", "Cole", 22),
  Person("Dan", "Jones", 20)
]).groupBy(Person::getLastName, count())

returns [{"Cole", 3}, {"Jones", 1}]
```

countDistinct:

```java
from([
  Person("Ann", "Cole", 20),
  Person("Beth", "Cole", 20),
  Person("Carl", "Cole", 30),
  Person("Dan", "Jones", 20)
]).groupBy(Person::getLastName, countDistinct(Person::getAge))

returns [{"Cole", 2}, {"Jones", 1}]
```

Do these examples make the difference clear?